# MIPS bad address/ Exception

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

The code is a recursive block for calculating the factorial of a number. I am getting an exception at PC (bad address in text). I am taking a look at the trace but am not sure where the problem really is, other than the fact that my PC is showing garbage values. I am attaching the code down below.

```
.data
    prompt: .asciiz "Enter the n"
.text
    main:
        #User I/O
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, prompt
        syscall
        li $v0, 5
        syscall
        add $a0, $v0, $zero
        jal fact
        j finish
    fact:
        addi $sp, $sp, -8  #adding two elements (reserve space), since stacks start from higher mem address
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        sw $a0, 4($sp)

        slti $t0, $a0, 1
        beq $t0, $zero, loop

        addi $sp, $sp, 8
        addi $v0, $zero, 1

        jr $ra

    loop:
        addi $a0, $a0, -1
        jal fact    #stores address of the lw instruction and goes to label-->fact

    lw $a0, 0($sp)
    lw $ra, 4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8 #deleting 2 elements

    mul $v0, $v0, $a0
    jr $ra #until main ra, recursively go through fact(n)=fact(n-1)*n

    finish:
```

**Simulator Used : QtSpim**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Also am attaching the PC and register values in case it helps.
[Register values at the time of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x98Zn.png)

Comment: As you deleted your other question with bubble sort attempt, while I was trying to write one for my own fun, I'm posting it here, sorry: https://pastebin.com/bHFPdgbr

Comment: Sorry about that, wanted to re-write the entire code. Thanks for the contribution, here is the link of the GitHub repo were I am posting the code for the basics of MIPS, I can add your code there if you fancy it(PR). link: https://github.com/rahulkrishnan98/computer-organization-and-architecture

Comment: Feel free to include it in your git if you think it is worth it (I didn't specify license, but by posting it on SO it can be treated as PD or copyleft piece of code of course (I should have mention that in that pastebin). But especially try to understand what/how it does, and if you have any question about it, feel free to ask me here (use @Ped7g to notify me). GL. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single-step with your debugger to find out what went wrong when `lw $ra, 4($sp)`, and what you *actually* loaded and jumped to with `jr $ra`.  That instruction just jumps to whatever address in `$ra`, and is the most likely candidate for setting the PC to something bogus.

It looks like you save `$ra` to `0($sp)`, but restoring it from `4($sp)`, so you're swapping the arg and the return address.

Also, your `main` isn't saving its `$ra` on entry at all, so you won't be able to return from main.  You run a `jal` before saving `$ra`, so the only save/restore is inside `fact` (whose definition is mixed in with `main`?  Don't do that.  Instead of jumping over the definition of another function, just put code to return from main or make an exit system call at the bottom of main.)

Also you might be crashing when you `j finish`, which will fall off the end of your program into non-instructions.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. Single stepping with my debugger helped verify that I was indeed mixing up the return address.